# is there a way to remove an onmouseover=("") from html using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a loading screen that uses javascript for the increasing of the bar. once finished the animation (of the color), the elements (load, inside) will fall but the problem there, is if I move my mouse, the animation will re do aka sending only the red  element back to the original position.  I can't change the `onmouseover` to be anywhere else because I don't know any other way to get the `after()` to be triggered, cause I couldn't find a way trigger the animation basically as soon as the page loads and `onload` didn't work.

**Code**

```
const div3 = document.getElementById("inside");
const div4 = document.getElementById("load")
    
// after moving my mouse over the element it will do this
function after() {
  div3.style.animation = " bar 10s linear forwards";
}

// after the animation starts this listens and calls function End

div3.addEventListener("animationend", End);
  


// div4 is the body of the color and // div3 is the inside
// after this animation it will repeat the top one after moving my mouse
function End() {
  div4.style.animation = "fall 10s forwards ease-in-out";
  div3.style.animation = "fall 10s forwards ease-in-out";
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html onmouseover="after()">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Game</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>


  <barload>
    <load class="load" id="load"></load>
    <inside class="inside" id="inside"></inside>
  </barload>

</html>
```

**Snippet**

```js
const div3 = document.getElementById("inside");
    const div4 = document.getElementById("load")
    
function after() {
  div3.style.animation = " bar 10s linear forwards";
}



div3.addEventListener("animationend", End);


function End() {
  div4.style.animation = "fall 10s forwards ease-in-out";
  div3.style.animation = "fall 10s forwards ease-in-out";
}
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
}



.load {
  position: absolute;
  top: 70%;
  left: 40%;
  width: 20%;
  height: 14px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #27282c;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px 4px #27282c;
  background: grey;
}

.inside {
 position: absolute;
  top: 70%;
  left: 40%;
  width: 0.1%;
  height: 14px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid #27282c;
}

@keyframes bar {
  0% {width: 0.1%;}
  10% {width: 4%;}
  20% {width: 5%;}
  30% {width: 6%;}
  40% {width: 12%;}
  50% {width: 14%;}
  60% {width: 15%;}
  70% {width: 16%;}
  80% {width: 17%;}
  81% {width: 17%;}
  82% {width: 17%;}
  83% {width: 17.8%;}
  84% {width: 17.9%;}
  85% {width: 19%;}
  86% {width: 19.1%;}
  87% {width: 19.6%;}
  88% {width: 19.8%;}
  90% {width: 19.9%;}
  100% {width: 20%;}
}

@keyframes fall {
  0% {top: 70%}
  20% {transform: rotate(190deg);}
  100% {top: 150%;}
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html onmouseover="after()">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Game</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<barload>
      <load class="load" id="load"></load>
    <inside class="inside" id="inside"></inside>
  </barload>

</html>
```

Comment: Maybe introduce a variable that is set to true when first animation triggers, and if the variable is true in `after()`, then dont change the animation? But it sounds like you want it to happen on page-load and not mouseover.

Comment: onclick is fine also could you wright a answer to show me what you mean?

Comment: Have you tried this: `window.onload = function() { after(); }` ?

Comment: You want the animation to happen after load (regardless of user hover?), and you want it to always only happen once, correct? Then use `window.onload` and remove the `onmouseover`. Otherwise, please update your question so it only contains one problem.

Comment: Awesome, and welcome to StackOverflow. :)

Answer (score 1):

`window.onload = function() { after(); }` has worked great and would help a lot in a instance like mine.

```js
window.onload = function() { after(); }

const div3 = document.getElementById("inside");
    const div4 = document.getElementById("load")
    
function after() {
  div3.style.animation = " bar 10s linear forwards";
}



div3.addEventListener("animationend", End);


function End() {
  div4.style.animation = "fall 10s forwards ease-in-out";
  div3.style.animation = "fall 10s forwards ease-in-out";
}
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
}



.load {
  position: absolute;
  top: 70%;
  left: 40%;
  width: 20%;
  height: 14px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #27282c;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px 4px #27282c;
  background: grey;
}

.inside {
 position: absolute;
  top: 70%;
  left: 40%;
  width: 0.1%;
  height: 14px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid #27282c;
}

@keyframes bar {
  0% {width: 0.1%;}
  10% {width: 4%;}
  20% {width: 5%;}
  30% {width: 6%;}
  40% {width: 12%;}
  50% {width: 14%;}
  60% {width: 15%;}
  70% {width: 16%;}
  80% {width: 17%;}
  81% {width: 17%;}
  82% {width: 17%;}
  83% {width: 17.8%;}
  84% {width: 17.9%;}
  85% {width: 19%;}
  86% {width: 19.1%;}
  87% {width: 19.6%;}
  88% {width: 19.8%;}
  90% {width: 19.9%;}
  100% {width: 20%;}
}

@keyframes fall {
  0% {top: 70%}
  20% {transform: rotate(190deg);}
  100% {top: 150%;}
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Game</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<barload>
      <load class="load" id="load"></load>
    <inside class="inside" id="inside"></inside>
  </barload>

</html>
```